# Ruby / Savon Model with dynamic URL

Tags: ruby, savon

I'd like to make a Savon Model but pass the URL of the WSDL when I initialize a client. Something like this:

```
class MyService
  extend Savon::Model
  client :wsdl self.url

  def initialize(url)
    self.url = url
  end
end
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client and operations are class-level methods(macros), so you just need to reference them with a self.class from inside the constructor.

So, here is an example of a working dynamic MyService class that takes the url of the endpoint as well as which operations you want to perform, comma-separated...

```
require 'savon' # I am assuming savon 2.4.0 here...

class MyService
  extend Savon::Model

  def initialize(url, *operations)
    self.class.client wsdl: url
    operations.each { |operation| self.class.operations operation }
  end
end

url = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"
service = MyService.new(url, :get_quote)
response = service.get_quote(message: { symbol: "AAPL" })

puts response.body[:get_quote_response][:get_quote_result]
```

Sample output

```
<StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>AAPL</Symbol><Last>592.98</Last><Date>5/2/2014</Date><Time>11:55am</Time>     <Change>+1.50</Change><Open>592.89</Open><High>594.20</High><Low>589.71</Low><Volume>3406189</Volume><MktCap>510.8B</MktCap><PreviousClose>591.48</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>+0.25%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>388.87 - 599.43</AnnRange><Earns>41.727</Earns><P-E>14.17</P-E><Name>Apple Inc.</Name></Stock></StockQuotes>
```